# themeing os user edit profile page

Tags: 7, theming

I am doing theming of user edit profile page

Now i have three fields here

Password, currentpassword, confirm password

What are their field items

i have tried

```
    <?php print render($user_profile['account']['pass']['pass1']); ?>
<?php print render($user_profile['account']['pass']['pass2']);
```

Which is not working

Also i am not sure about third filed

Anybody can tell me

Thanks

Comment: Checkout DEVEL module. It will give you a detailed look of all the fields in a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
<?php print render($user_profile['account']['pass']); ?>
```

The password field is only split into 2 in a `#process` function, and you can't access the separate fields before the element is rendered. To do that you would need to provide a `#theme` property for the element itself, and write a function/template that returns the desired markup.